# How to make 2nd async method run after 1st async method has finished

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have two `async` methods that I run in succession, but I need to 2nd method called to execute only after the 1st method has resolved

```js
class Class {
  constructor() {}

  async foo() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(1);
    }, 2000);
  }

  async bar() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(2);
    }, 0);
  }
}

(async() => {
  const obj = new Class();
  await obj.foo();
  await obj.bar();
})()
```

The output of the above code:

```
> 2
> 1
```

What I need is for the output to be:

```
> 1
> 2
```

There's clearly some gaps in my knowledge regarding `async/await` functions.

Is it possible for me to achieve this? Because of my gap in knowledge, is there a reason I *shouldn't* be wanting this? Any helped would be much apprecaited.

Comment: As written, neither foo nor bar is async.  Is the goal to do something, delay two seconds, and then do something else?  Are the two "somethings" also async?

Comment: Ah, I understand you. Thanks to you and Michael, I see where I was going wrong/misunderstanding Promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a custom promise that will resolve when the `setTimeout` finishes, you can't just use regular `async` functions. Like this:

```js
class Class {
  constructor() {}

  foo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(1);
      resolve();
    }, 2000));
  }

  bar() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(2);
      resolve();
    }, 0));
  }
}

(async() => {
  const obj = new Class();
  await obj.foo();
  await obj.bar();
})()
```

If you want to learn more about promises, then you might want to read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: I see now where I've been going wrong, and for some time now. Thanks for you help :)